# Has a graduated site ever closed down?

Tags: discussion, closed-sites

Sometimes, sites in beta can be shut down due to stuff like lack of activity. Has this ever happened to a Stack Exchange Network site that had already left beta? If so, what caused that?

Comment: Yes. [The Windows Phone SE site has been archived](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383855/289691)