# Should Windows Phone site be removed from SEDE?

Tags: support, bug, data-explorer, closed-sites

I have noticed that it is possible to see Windows Phone as one of the sites where one can run SEDE queries. As an example, here is a [query listing the recent posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/windowsphone/query/1792908/most-recent-posts).

This query shows the date as the most recent post from as September 2022. This announcement was posted in November 2022: [The Windows Phone SE site has been archived](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383855)
The URL https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ redirects to Area51 page where you can read that the site "was closed 11 months ago."<sup>1</sup>

It seems that in the past closed sites used to be removed from SEDE manually, at least that's how I understood the answer to this question: [When are closed sites removed from SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331829)
Journeyman Geek asked about some stuff related to this site, including SEDE, in this answer: [The Windows Phone SE site has been archived](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383954) - but there wasn't any official response to that answer. (The comments there just confirm that this is done manually.)

Should the Windows Phone site be removed from SEDE at some point?

---

<sup>1</sup>Although it was pointed out in another Q&A that there are few remaining questions that do not redirect to Area51: [Why is there one remaining page on Windows Phone Meta SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390904)

Comment: I have tagged this both ([tag:bug]) and ([tag:support]). Basically, if the answer is that this should be done after some time, I would consider it a bug. And if the answer is an explanation why it is better to keep such sites in SEDE, I can see t as a support question. (But maybe more experienced users around here have better suggestions on the choice of tags.)

Comment: I've never been much good with tags :D. I do think its really a matter of whether its useful or not over anything else, as well as the 'lift' of removing it. I'd not consider it a bug unless someone *forgot* to, or it got lost in the shuffle.

Comment: Actually in its current state it's neither a bug nor support, it's a discussion as you just ask for opinion.

Comment: Anyway, yes it should be removed, and it can only be done manually by staff after we ask for that.

Comment: Whats the practical benefit to spending the developer time to remove it? Is it causing any harm by being present?

Comment: @Makyen Well, that's probably the question mainly for the SE team - since in the past they used to remove the closed sites (according to the linked answer). I consider this a rather minor issue - but since Glorfindel [advised me to post it as a separate bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1317898), I did so. One possible drawback that I encountered - when running networkwide-queries in SEDE, you count some stuff which no longer exists. (But as I said, I do consider this a minor thing.)

Comment: In the past, closed sites have always been removed from SEDE. To be honest, if that isn't done anymore for whatever reason (including "it costs time we don't have"), that is fine with me, as long as it's documented somewhere as being the current policy, so we can refer to it in the future.